# What is an example of a positive recurrent Continuous-time Markov Chain whose embedded Markov Chain is null recurrent?

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process

Would taking any null recurrent discrete-time markov chain and constructing a $Q$-matrix from its transition matrix work?

Comment: You can construct a simple example by a chain with states $\{0,1,2,...\}$ where every transition either increases the state by 1, or goes back to zero.

Comment: If by "embedded" you mean a Markov chain of the form $Y_n=X(n)$, $n=0,1,2,\ldots$, where $X$ s a continuous-time Markov chain, then $Y$ inherits the positive recurrence of $X$. This because the positive recurrence of $X$ implies the existence of a stationary (probability) distribution $\pi$, and it is easy to check that $\pi$ is also a stationary distribution for $Y$, ensuring the *positive* recurrence of $Y$.

Comment: @JohnDawkins no by embedded I meant the jump process. Sorry if that was unclear

Comment: Same story: an invariant distribution for the continuous-time chain is invariant for the discrete-time chain.

Comment: @JohnDawkins Positive recurrence isn't equivalent for both. An invariant distribution for the continuous-time chain gives you an invariant measure for the jump chain but it's not necessarily a distribution.

Comment: You are absolutely right — my bad!  Now that I am thinking about it more correctly, an example could be made from simple symmetric random walk on $\{0,1,2,\ldots\}$ as the null-recurrent discrete-time chain, and the continuous-time chain a birth-and-death process on the same sate space with birth rates $\lambda_n = \rho^n$ ($\rho>1$) and death rates $\mu_n=\lambda_n$ for $n\ge 1$. The farther away the chain is, the faster it exits states so as to get back to $0$.

Comment: @JohnDawkins Yes, that works perfectly! Thank you!