# Positive/Null recurrence of Continuous Time Markov chain and its embedded chain

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

I understand that all 4 combinations of positive/null recurrence of a continuous Markov chain and its embedded jump chain are possible. Recurrence and transience are class properties and thus are similar for both chains, however positive/null recurrence is related to time information which we lose in the embedded jump chain, but I struggle to find concrete examples to support this claim.

Comment: Similar/same question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3770335/what-is-an-example-of-a-positive-recurrent-continuous-time-markov-chain-whose-em